# How to increase the width of a PopupMenuEntry in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I created a horizontal popup menu but i cant increase the width of the popupMenuEntry because the default width is too short for my use case.  I tried to set the child of my popupMenuEntry to `double.infinity` and `MediaQuery.of(context).sized.width` but nothing is happening..
It looks like ok in the emulator but when i tested out in the actual device, its too small thats why i need to resize it to at least 90-95% of the screen width.

here is my implementation of my popupMenu.[image]

```html
class ReactionPopupMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReactionPopupMenu(
      {Key? key, required this.onSelect, required this.child, this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);
  final void Function(String) onSelect;
  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;

  @override
  State<ReactionPopupMenu> createState() => _ReactionPopupMenuState();
}

class _ReactionPopupMenuState extends State<ReactionPopupMenu>
    with CustomPopupMenu {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: widget.onTap,
        onTapDown: storePosition,
        onLongPress: () => this.showMenu(
                context: context,
                shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                items: [
                  CustomedPopupEntry(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: [
                            for (var i = 0; i < kEmojies.length; i++)
                              ReactiveEmoji(
                                  emoji: kEmojies[i],
                                  onTap: () =>
                                      Navigator.pop(context, kValue[i]))
                          ]),
                    ),
                  )
                ]).then(
                (value) => value == null ? null : widget.onSelect(value)),
        child: widget.child);
  }
}


mixin CustomPopupMenu<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  Offset? _tapPosition;

  /// Pass this method to an onTapDown parameter to record the tap position.
  void storePosition(TapDownDetails details) =>
      _tapPosition = details.globalPosition;

  /// Use this method to show the menu.
  // ignore: avoid_shadowing_type_parameters
  Future<T?> showMenu<T>({
    required BuildContext context,
    required List<PopupMenuEntry<T>> items,
    T? initialValue,
    double? elevation,
    String? semanticLabel,
    ShapeBorder? shape,
    Color? color,
    bool captureInheritedThemes = true,
    bool useRootNavigator = false,
  }) {
    // final RenderObject? overlay =
    //     Overlay.of(context)!.context.findRenderObject();

    return material.showMenu<T>(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
        _tapPosition!.dx,
        _tapPosition!.dy,
        _tapPosition!.dx,
        _tapPosition!.dy,
      ),
      items: items,
      initialValue: initialValue,
      elevation: elevation,
      semanticLabel: semanticLabel,
      shape: shape,
      color: color,
      useRootNavigator: useRootNavigator,
    );
  }
}

class CustomedPopupEntry<T> extends PopupMenuEntry<T> {
  const CustomedPopupEntry({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CustomedPopupEntryState();

  @override
  double get height => 100;

  @override
  bool represents(T? value) => false;
}

class _CustomedPopupEntryState extends State<CustomedPopupEntry> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.child;
}



class ReactiveEmoji extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReactiveEmoji({Key? key, required this.emoji, required this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);
  final String emoji;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.046,
        backgroundImage: AssetImage(emoji),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your above code is not re-useable for testing the feature out. So please add code that could be reused by others to help you out.

Comment: i think its generic enough to test to other device..they can disregard the onTap function and for the  ReactiveEmoji widget that is just a circle avatar with a background image..they can put any image or just disregard the background image for testing because only the width of the CustomedPopupEntry is what we are trying to find out.

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin you can use that inside an empty screen for testing. give a child of anything visible like text or icon and give an empty onTap and onSelect Callbacks. and disregard the ReactiveEmoji widget because that has nothing to do with the width. long press it and the popup menu should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not with adding more width to popUpMenu. you should make your emoji list scrollable, so when use it in small device it could be scrolled. So wrap your emoji row with SingleChildScrollView and set its scrollDirection to  horizontal.

Comment: that can be but the first thing to do is to resize the width to the max. if the max width is still not enough to fit the content then thats the time we will make it scrollable. and for use cases that you need a popupmenuEntry with a full width then how?

Comment: see these links,[one](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64918), [two](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41032#issuecomment-534991065)

Comment: no answer found on both links, the suggestion made there is to use PopupMenuButton which doesnt fit my use case because i only need to popup the menu on longPress thats why i need to use Gesturedetector. and even i can switch to PopupMenuBotton, it still needs an item builder that accepts a list of PopupMenyEntry which is not resizeable.